# How to use a specific resources when it is provisioned in terraform list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have created an AWS s3 module to create a number (more than 1) of S3 as in a list. How do I use one S3 from this list to call it somewhere?

E.g. my S3 module looks like this:

```
module "s3" {
  source      = "../"
  env         = "sandbox"
  bucket_name = ["bucket-1", "bucket-2", "bucket-3", "bucket-4", "bucket-5"]
  region = "eu-west-1"
  create_s3bucket           = true
  enable_replication        = false
  s3_object_prefix          = { my_folder = "my_folder" }
  enable_s3_object_prefix   = false
  s3_object_expiration_days = 1

  providers = {
    aws.primary   = aws.default
    aws.secondary = aws.xxxx
  }
}
```

I'd like to use `bucket-2` in IAM role policies or lambda invocation or use it in a DMS service. How do I do that?

I am currently creating a separate S3 module for each bucket. As the list grows, the file size increases further. I don't get the use of the module in this use-case unless we are able to pick one resource as we need.

Comment: What is the starting point? What works and what does not work? What does your module definition look like now? How do you end up having to reference your bucket?

Comment: What is the source code of the module?